# Pushing String into database utilizing nodeJS and mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I am new to JS and I am utilizing the MEAN stack to create a place where students can add classes to their user profile. I already have a session store in my database, so "req.user" will return the currently logged in user information and specifically "req.user.id" will return the currently logged in user's id. Also, I have figured out how to search a course in my database from my application. Ultimately, my goal is that when the user makes the post request to search in the database, I also want those "values" to be pushed into the classes "key". I have provided two options, both of which do not add the respective strings to the database. Thank you for any help!

**Portion of Search.JS Option #1**

```
router.post('/', ensureAuthenticated, function (req,res,next) {
    var query = {course: req.body.coursename};
    db.collection('courses').find(query).toArray()
    .then(db.collection('DefaultUser').update({_id: req.user.id}, {$push: {classes: req.body.coursename}}));
    res.render('search', {title: 'search'})
});
```

**Portion of Search.JS Option #2**

```
router.post('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req,res,next) {
    var query = {course: req.body.coursename};
    db.collection('courses').find(query).toArray((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        } else {
            db.collection('DefaultUser').updateOne({_id: '5c17161d3347e79410ff29ba'}, {
                                                                $push: {
                                                                    classes: req.body.coursename
                                                                }
                                                            })
            console.log(results)
            res.render('search', {courses: results, title: 'search'})
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips may help:

1. `req.body` will hold nothing if you forget to use [`app.use(express.urlencoded())`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded) to parse the posted data.
2. You may use `ObjectId('<string>')` (in option #2) for finding and updating queries, not just the string, because mongodb stores `_id` as [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId) type by default.
3. You may use [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) instead of `$push` modifier to add a unique element to an array, or you may get one student subscribed with two more same class, if he repeatedly submit the form.
4. In your code, you find in the `courses` collection first and then update, but since you did nothing with the find result, it is not necessary (empty result does not throw any error). Checking the data is valid is good practice, if you would like to do so, in both options, you need to use [`findOne`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) instead of `find` to make sure the course is existed, and `.then(course => {/* check if the course is null and then throws an error */} )`.

I don't have the full code of your project so I can only guess there may be the problems listed above, wish you good luck!